# How can I run a file from github?

Tags: android

I am trying to run a 'game' from github (The powder toy), but I can't figure out how to run it. I don't have any neat external programs to run files, but I believe I do not need one because I already have Sans Fight Simulator https://jcw87.github.io/c2-sans-fight/  that I play sometimes that I downloaded from github, but I can't run the Powder Toy game. Here is the link: https://github.com/The-Powder-Toy/The-Powder-Toy

I tried downloading the ZIP file and running it on my computer, but I can't run a downloaded file. I went to code and put the Https into a new page on my bookmarks and tried opening that, (I have the Sans Fight Simulator bookmarked) and opening it that way but it only opened the Github site where it shows the main page for the Powder Toy.

I'm sorry if this question was already asked, but I can't find an answer anywhere.